# google chrome android

Tags: chrome-for-android

What is the difference between each option of the following flags in google chrome for android?

Please, Can anyone explain me what does each option of these flags?

#metrics-settings-android

#web-otp-backend

#lens-camera-assisted-search

#trust-tokens

#enable-google-srp-isolated-prerender-nsp

#use-sync-sandbox

#document-transition-slowdown-factor

#contextual-search-new-settings

#explore-sites

#related-searches-in-bar

#translate-force-trigger-on-english

#webnotes-stylize

#enable-google-srp-isolated-prerender-probing

#web-feed

#omnibox-on-focus-suggestions-contextual-web

#mbi-mode

#enable-resampling-scroll-events-experimental-prediction

#enable-fenced-frames

#context-menu-translate-with-google-lens

#continuous-search

#scroll-capture

#draw-predicted-ink-point

Answer (score 1):

You can type in chrome address/location bar this command `chrome://flags` and read about almost all flags.
I.e. `#trust-tokens`
"Enable Trust Tokens" - Enables prototype Trust Token API (https://github.com/wicg/trust-token-api) - Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android